# "80710a06" Error when attempting to visit Tumblr from my PS3

Tags: ps3, technical-issues

I tried to visit Tumblr but instead I got this error "80710a06".

When I searched I came up with three or four articles/discussions about when PSN went down three years ago. But PSN is not down and I can browse other sites fine.

Anyone know what this error means? or why it gives me the error on Tumblr only?

Comment: seems like the PS3 browser cannot find the site. Moving to [gaming.se], as it deals with PS3 than tumblr

Comment: assuming you found at least this: https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4197/kw/80710A06  Basically says, make sure your internet is set up correctly, or try again later.  Have you ever been able to use tumblr from your ps3?

Comment: @turbo Yea, I've always been able to access it. I had a problem a couple months ago with not being able to log into Tumblr but I could ignore that for the most part, now I can't visit the main site at all. Various tumblr accounts are still visitable though.